# NFCEE Execution environment : hardware or library module?

Tags: nfc

I wanted to know what NFC Execution environment means actually. In forum documents it is described as *"An environment, either built into the NFCC or connected to the NFCC, where NFC applications are executed. The NFCEE may be included in entities with various form factors, some of which can be removable or replaceable."*. But the Device Host(an application microprocessor like OMAP or Snapdragon) is the one which interacts with NFCC, as per my understanding in the mobile environment. Can anyone give me a example of what NFCEE can be - I mean is it another hardware module(if yes, which) or an android library to execute apps? What does "form factor" refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Execution Environment is in most cases a hardware module.

Newer SIM cards have a pin to connect the SIM to the NFC chip. Inside the SIM an application (payment for example) can run in a secure environment and talk to the NFC chip. Payment goes from a sales terminal through the NFC chip directly into the SIM without ever passing data through the application processor. So there is no easy way for malware to monitor or modify the payment process. That's a simplified view of the secure aspect.

Other execution environments are:

- Embedded Secure Elements. These are in a nutshell SIM cards that are in the same package as the NFC controller chip. Your Android Phone most likely has one of these, called the SmartMX chip.
- SWP (Single Wire Protocol) enabled SD-Cards. Same thing as a SIM, but in the form factor of an SD card.

The concept doesn't end here. There are for example experiments to move the execution environment to the application processor. For ARM CPUs there is the TrustZone extension which allows to execute code on the main CPU while still beeing secure.

In the Android API Execution Environments do two things:

- they allow you to enable or disable the secure element by setting a route. The route configures when the secure element is active (e.g. has access to the NFC chip) and when disabled. Currently there are two routes in use: Route off (turns off the entire EE) and Route_OnWhenScreenOn (EE active when screen is on and unlocked).
- For secure elements that are connected exclusively to the NFC chip (embedded secure elements) the Execution Environment also offers a secure way to exchange data from the application processor to the embedded secure element. This is used to install applications within the embedded secure element (among other things).

That's it in a nutshell.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My doubt is cleared. This wiki must be present wherever there is a mention of EE. Was surprised to know of the SIM+NFC hardware!

Comment: @Nils Pipenbrinck: Is it possible to use NFCEE to send messages to the SIM card (and not the embedded SE)?

Comment: @MohammadBanisaeid No. That is not possible. There is no way for the NFC chip to send data to the SIM. You may access it via the Radio RIL interface though.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: Thank you. Do you know any tutorial describing how to use RIL for SIM communications? Is it related to SEEK project?

Comment: @MohammadBanisaeid Yes, it is related to SEEK. How it works is however dependent on the exact device.